# .xml File In Android studio is not opening

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-studio-arctic-fox

*I was trying to start my start android devv so I installed android studio following a online course after installation when i tried to open .xml file isn't opening*
*message at bottom is:*

**Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt**

[ERROR IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWnto.png)

[ERROR IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acjJv.png)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org/jetbrains/kotlin/config/LanguageVersion

> org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.LanguageVersion

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/config/LanguageVersion
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.FragmentConsistencyChecks.(ConsistencyChecker.kt:24)
  **SOME FILES ** org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.LanguageVersion
  ... 196 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.

The Gradle Terms of Service have not been agreed to.

For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-terms-of-service.

Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-enterprise-config.

Answer (score 0):

First check your latest kotlin version i think you are usinv old one or try to reinstall and download all sdk components files which you missed.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of kotlin is not compatible with some versions of gradle, check the version of kotlin and gradle, update, then clean and rebuild the project